# Display Mat-hint only on corresponding input focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-hint element added in my html.
I want to display mat-hint only when users focus is on corresponding form-field & hide the hint on focusout.
How to achieve this scenario for all form-fields.

```
<mat-hint align="end">Max 50 characters</mat-hint>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(focus)` and `(focusout)` with reference called `focusState`

```
<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusState = true" (focusout)="focusState = false">
<mat-hint align="end" *ngIf="focusState">Max 50 characters</mat-hint>
```

### Edit

To handle the multiple items

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
   <input #item name="date" type="text" (focus)="item.alt = true" (focusout)="item.alt = false">
   <mat-hint align="end" *ngIf="item.alt">Max 50 characters</mat-hint>
</div>
```

Comment: I loved the solution. I have used this stuff for other use cases. The problem i am facing is little different. I am having a formArray which is bulk saved.
If I set this declare this variable all the inputs will be affected.If i modify object my ngrx store will be impacted. hence confused what would be idle solution to such problems

Comment: It looks like you want to handle the multiple items of formArray. You might be using `*ngFor` for iteration. For such kind  of scenario, you can create a separate variable which for each items and performs the same operation independently.   Update the answer and here the link which will help to implement this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckqmvs

Comment: Yes, this is the solution i am using, by adding property in each object. i was looking for solution without modifying my actual object. but thats ok, i will stick with object alteration for now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by css only.  Hide when not focused.

```
.mat-form-field:not(.mat-focused) .mat-hint {
    display: none;
}
```